# PyCharmCE перестал видеть selenium пакет

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, mac, pycharm

коллеги.
PyCharm for mac не ставит пакет selenium. Выдает ошибку и вот такой скрин: 
[image: ошибка]

Вот такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/packaging_tool.py", line 192, in main
    retcode = do_install(pkgs)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/packaging_tool.py", line 109, in do_install
    return pip.main(['install'] + pkgs)
AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'main'
```

Попробовал обновить pip в терминале. вот выдал:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте текст ошибки в вопрос. А так похоже, pip сломался.

Comment: А версия pip у вас 10.0.1? Попробуйте ввести в консоли: `pip install --upgrade pip==9.0.3`

Comment: @gil9red Попробовал. Вот что выдал (скрин к вопросу приложил)

Comment: Тоже самое `sudo pip install --upgrade pip==9.0.3` только с `sudo`. Ошибка у вас `Permission denied`.

Comment: @СергейБогданов, автор, у вас питон3 используется? Заметил по консоли, что у вас есть и питон 2.7 (по умолчанию входит в мак). Если у вас все-таки питон 3, тогда пишите pip3 вместо pip, или пишите полный путь до pip, чтобы pip питона 2 не вызвался (можно еще у конкретноо питона вызвать pip, типо python3 -m pip). Потом, если в ошибке ругательства про "permissions", тогда скорее всего прав не хватает, поэтому команду нужно выполнить с sudo: `sudo pip3 install`

Comment: Я поставил пакеты через sudo  и теперь не могу ими пользоваться прав нет (ожидаемо). как и где мне поменять права и прописать путь?